# Would like to generate custom unique key and handle it multiple request at same time

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table as below in sql database server which containing a varchar column and maintaining it as custom unique key programattically using linq to entity. I am pulling from database and splitting and increment and saving but i would like to know what will happes when multiple request comes at same time, that could be fail my logic or will handled by sql server.

```
-----------------
Id      |  Code
-----------------
1       | BA0001
2       | BA0002
3       | BA0003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what will happes when multiple request comes at same time

You will get a PK violation.

In SQL Server you can use a Sequence object to generate the key like this:

```
create sequence seq_t
start with 1
increment by 1

create table t
(
  id varchar(20) default concat('BA',format((next value for seq_t),'0000')) primary key, 
  a int
)
```